# How is the name of the controller passed in this ASP.NET tutorial?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been following along in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) ASP.NET tutorial. In the beginning of the controller, there is the following code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
```

From my understanding, the ApiController attribute declares this class as a controller, and the Route attribute declares the base route for all other routes in the controller.

When you scroll down, they test the api with a URL of `http://localhost:<port>/api/books`. So this means that [controller] is equal to books. I can't find where this "books" is passed in as the controller name.

The only time where some string "books" is passed in is in the appsettings.json file, and this is meant for the collection name in MongoDB. Also the string is "Books" not "books".

Also my second question is how does this replacement of [controller] with books work. Like what is the name of this syntax? I don't even know what to google to get more information.

Comment: The concept you're struggling to understand is called [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1). And keep in mind that although URLs are technically case sensitive, they're most often treated as though they're not by many frameworks.

Comment: Adding to @mason's link: [Token replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)

Comment: The controller name is based on the type name. However the word "Controller" is always stripped off the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RouteCollection` actually provides the collection of route information to use them by the controller actions.
When the `RouteTable` was registered  and our `RouteTable` has the collection of routes as `RouteCollection`. And when the request comes in, it matches the pattern from these records of the `RouteTable` and if it founds the record of route then the request goes to the relevant controller action otherwise 404 error.

[image]

But don't take it so much so much serious, `RouteTable` doesn't physically exist but it works logically like a table. So the name attribute of each route map should be unique.

The URL path `/api/books` and will extract the route values `{ controller = Books, action = Index }` by tokenizing the path. MVC will attempt to locate a controller named `BooksController` automatically and run the action Details.

The following table demonstrates example route templates and their behavior:
[image]

> Also my second question is how does this replacement of [controller]
> with books work. Like what is the name of this syntax? I don't even
> know what to google to get more information.

**The [controller] and [action] tokens of Attribute Routing**

By using the `[controller]` token in your attribute routes you can ensure that the controller name in the route, is kept in sync with the name of the controller class.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")] //     http://localhost:<port>/api/books
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase


[Route("api/[controller]")] //     http://localhost:<port>/api/hello
[ApiController]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
```

If you use `[Route("api/books")]`, renaming the Controller or action name does not require the route template to be changed.

```
[Route("api/[books]")] //     http://localhost:<port>/api/books
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase

[Route("api/books")]  //          http://localhost:<port>/api/books still works
[ApiController]
public class HelloController : ControllerBase
```

> Related links for learning

[Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) provided by @mason
[Token replacement in route templates [controller], [action], [area]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) provided by @John